# Gate characteristics of different platforms

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, experimental-realization

I would like to know if there is a place in which is summarized the gate characteristics of the different quantum computer existing (IBM,Google, others).

For instance, which kind of two qubit gate they physically implement. Their quality, etc.

From Sycamore paper I am able to access some of those date from google. From IBM I am struggling to find their characteristics on internet. I am particularly interested to know what is the physical two qubit gate they realize.

Answer (score 2):

For **IBM** machines, you can just select a provider backend that is available to you and look at its specifications. For example, if I want to look at their `ibmq_santiago` machine specification I can run:

```
%matplotlib inline
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, IBMQ
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')
backend
```

Which will output the following Widget:

[image]

There you can see that the two qubit gate that is **native** to this machine is **CNOT gate**.

---

If you want to go further and look at the gates specifications on each qubit, for instance the pulse duration, then you can do something like:

```
print('Gate Pulse Duration Time on Different Qubit: \n')
for gate in backend.properties().gates:
    print("{} gate on qubits {} duration is {}{}".format(gate.name, gate.qubits, gate.parameters[1].value, gate.parameters[1].unit))
```

which will print out something like:

[image]